# how to set Target in quanteda's "textstat_keyness" function associated with "date"

Tags: r, quanteda

It's working as `target = year(dfmat_news$datee) >= 2016`

```
tstat_key <- textstat_keyness(hr_dfm,
                          measure = "chi2",sort = TRUE, correction = c("default"),
                          target = year(dfmat_news$datee) >= 2016)
```

AS I set  `target= date(dfmat_news$datee) >= 2016-02-01`

It's not working.

datee=(YYYY-MM-DD) in date format

How to set "target" with date in function "textstat_keyness" in R Package quanteda?
THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the comparison operator (`>=`) is trying to compare a numeric value to a "date" formatted field `dfmat_news$datee`, and this is not producing what you expect.  `2016-02-01` evaluates to `2013` which compares to Date fields that are very different when used as integers.  For instance:

```
> as.numeric(as.Date("2016-01-01"))
[1] 16801
```

So you should brush up on date operations in R, starting with `?Ops.Date`.

Here's a reproducible example solving this in the way that you want, using `textstat_keyness()`.  You can see that this works on an expression that evaluates to a logical.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.1

# this has a date field, but the package must be installed
# from https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.corpora
data(data_corpus_sotu, package = "quanteda.corpora")

hr_dfm <- dfm(tail(data_corpus_sotu, 10)) %>%
  dfm_remove(stopwords("en"))

hr_dfm$Date
##  [1] "2011-01-25" "2012-01-24" "2013-02-12" "2014-01-28" "2015-01-20"
##  [6] "2016-01-12" "2017-02-28" "2018-01-30" "2019-02-05" "2020-02-04"

textstat_keyness(hr_dfm, target = hr_dfm$Date >= "2016-01-01") %>%
  head()
##   feature     chi2            p n_target n_reference
## 1   thank 65.17899 6.661338e-16       85          12
## 2    much 33.17024 8.443305e-09       49           9
## 3   great 28.21748 1.084209e-07       66          22
## 4       , 21.21601 4.103217e-06     1822        1791
## 5    drug 20.95085 4.712182e-06       21           1
## 6  border 20.25901 6.763404e-06       27           4

textstat_keyness(hr_dfm, target = rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), each = 5)) %>%
  head()
##   feature     chi2            p n_target n_reference
## 1   thank 65.17899 6.661338e-16       85          12
## 2    much 33.17024 8.443305e-09       49           9
## 3   great 28.21748 1.084209e-07       66          22
## 4       , 21.21601 4.103217e-06     1822        1791
## 5    drug 20.95085 4.712182e-06       21           1
## 6  border 20.25901 6.763404e-06       27           4
```